# Error when importing Google Play Services library (Could not write file)

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, google-play-services

When trying to import Google Play Services library in Eclipse, I get the following error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a permissions problem from Windows. Try trying it with a file path outside of "Program Files (x86)"

Comment: @ChristopherPerry - Did you move entire eclipse folder to something like C: or just the library project you were trying to import?

Answer (score 2):

Copy google-play-services_lib to a location like `C:\Development\` and import from there.

Do not put google-play-services_lib inside the workspace. Eclipse seems to have a bug when importing project that is already in workspace.

Answer (score 0):

First install from sdk manager, after this, import from your sdk folder like this:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install